# Problems on orthogonality and tangency in 3-space.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

1. Find the set of all points $(a,b,c)$ in 3-space for which the two spheres $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ intersect orthogonally.
2. A cylinder whose equation is $y=f(x)$ is tangent to the surface $z^2+2xz+y=0$.

For the first one, at the set of points, $\nabla f \cdot \nabla g$ should be $0$, where $f$ and $g$ each correspond to the first two spheres. Doing this, I get $4x(x-a)+4y(y-b)+4z(z-c)=0$, which gives the function of a sphere centered at $(a/2,b/2,c/2)$. However, the answer of this problem is a sphere with center at the origin and radius $\sqrt{2}$.

For the second one, I tried solving it by setting the first equation as $F(x,y,z)=f(x)-y$ and the second one as $G(x,y,z)=z^2+2xz+y$. But I do not know how to progress further from here.

I guess I'm not good at solving these kind of geometric problems yet. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (1), your equation is correct. You should also combine that equation with the two original equation. The points are on the intersection too. So 
$$4x(x-a)+4y(y-b)+4z(z-c)=0\implies 4x^2-4ax+4y^2-4by+4z^2-4cz=0$$
Combining this with $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$
$$4-4zx-4by-4cz=0$$
Now the first equation is $x^2-2ax+a^2+y^2-2by+b^2+z^2-2cz+c^2=1$. Combining this with equation 2 gives you $-2ax-2by-2cz=-a^2-b^2-c^2$. This and the above equation will give you what you want.

For (2), the gradient vectors of the two surfaces are equal at the tangent point
$$(-f'(x),1,0)=(2z,1,2z+2x)$$
From here see if you can find $f(x)$.

Comment: It's even easier to do the part (1) by actually trying to draw the spheres roughly and using well known pythagorean theorem to get $r_1^2+r_2^2=C_1C_2$ where C is centre. gives $1+1=a^2+b^2+c^2$ ^^. , i think atleast.

Comment: @Mann: Good point. In this special case, it's indeed easier to just draw the pictures and use geometry.

Comment: I think it's worth noting why the gradients must be equal when the cylinder is tangent to the surface as opposed to just scalar multiples of one another. That the cylinder is tangent to the surface is not enough to require that the gradients are equal. Tangency requires that
$$(-f(x),1,0) = k(2z,1,2x+2z)$$
Then as a result of the system of equations:
$$-f'(x) = 2kz$$
$$1  = k$$
$$0 = 2kx + 2kz$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the question 2.

Your cylinder has a parametric equation $(x,z) \mapsto (x, f(x), z)$. The second surface is defined by $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,z(x,y))$ where $z(x,y)$ is defined by the implicit equation you provide.

Based on that, you can compute the normal vectors of both surfaces at a point of intersection. Those two vectors should be dependent.

(Jean-Pierre http://www.mathcounterexamples.net)